# Is there a way that i can unregister a module from Jackson ObjectMapper?

Tags: json, jackson, jackson-modules

I'm registering `KeyDeseriliser` to `ObjectMapper`. After reading `JSON` I want to unregister this module. Because my `ObjectMapper` is static and I don't want to use this module in any other places.

```
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("EnhancedDatesModule", new Version(0, 1, 0, "test", "Test-id",
"testest"));
module.addKeyDeserializer(EncounterCURN.class, new MapKeyDeseriliser());
objectMapper.registerModule(module);
Map<EncounterCURN, Collection<EncounterTodo>> encounterTodosByEncounter = mapReader.readValue(nodes.get("todos"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can not do this. You should create another `ObjectMapper` and use it.

By the way, `static` fields this is a not a good habit of programming in Java. You should avoid situations like this where such kind of objects are `static`.

Comment: This is a particularly bad use of `static`, since it temporarily changes the state of a static field that's also used elsewhere.  This means that if the other code is called at the same time as this code is changing the `ObjectMapper` (e.g. if it's called by another thread), it could have a misconfigured `ObjectMapper` for some or all of the time it's using it, resulting in difficult to reproduce sporadic incorrect behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The module has a `setSerializers`, according to the docs:

```java
/**
 * Resets all currently configured serializers.
 */
public void setSerializers(SimpleSerializers s) {
    _serializers = s;
}
```

So, what you can do is call the setter with a new  empty `SimpleSerializers` object.

Disclaimer: I am not 100% sure how this will workout in from a thread-safety point of view.

Comment: This helped me, I had a class I was trying to unit test. I had two Unit tests in one test class. The class I was testing had a static `ObjectMapper` and `SimpleModule`. The second test used a modified Serialiser, to the first. The second test passed when run independently, but not when run together. By adding an initial `MODULE.setSerializers(null);` to the register serialisers allowed them to run together.

Comment: ARTA. I register other comments on static Mappers and Modules being a "code smell", perhaps for reasons I experienced! But I was doing this for efficiency. I believe ObjectMappers and Modules are considered "heavy-weight" Objects.